# Duplication assets files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

In my rails application I use two interfaces(for `user` and `admin`). Assets directory separated too(`assets` and `admin/assets`)
Today I need to implement same assets for both interfaces.

How I can do this and avoid duplication of files?

Comment: How did you include your `admin/assets` to the asset-pipeline ?

Comment: In `routes.rb` => `namespace :admin`. Create in `layout` folder `admin.html.erb`. `Assets` separated by folders, manifest files changed. In `admin` layout `css` and `js` tags defined for `admin/apllication`. Мaybe I did something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to place common for application assets in the default folder `app/assets` , and admin specific assets - in `app/admin/assets`. This way you'll have default assets, which would be overwritten by admin assets. For example: if you place `background-color: blue` in your `app/assets/stylesheets/mystyles.scss` , it will be overwritten by `background-color: red` in `app/assets/stylesheets/myadminstyles.scss` in admin's namespace.